# How can I connect two dictionaries in python?

Tags: python

I'm struggling a bit on a dictionary code in Python (mind I'm a new student without any earlier experience). The strings in this code is on Norwegian, hopefully that's not a problem. The code goes as follow

```
    participants_and_allergens = {"Ole":["gluten", "egg"],
                             "Silje":["shellfish", "nuts"],
                             "Ragnar":["milk", "fish"]}
print(participants_and_allergens.keys())

allergens_and_foods = {"Garlic bread": ["gluten", "egg"],
                             "Fish soup": ["shellfish", "fish"],
                             "Chocolate Cake": ["milk", "egg"]}

def write_name():
     name = input("What is your name?\n> ")#confirms the registration of the participant
     if not participants_og_allergener.get(name):
         print("Sorry,", name + " does not exist in the registry")
     else:
         print(name + " is registered and now confirmed")
         print(allergens)
         print(name + " has the allergens", allergens)
         allergens = participants_og_allergener.get(name)
         allergens_foods = allergens_and_foods.get("allergens")
         print(allergens_foods)

write_name()
```

Essentially, what I'm asking is, is there any way to connect to dictionaries, which are independent? When the user enters a name, it should result in values linked to the name coming out, and elements from another dictionary.

I have realized I'll have to use a for loop, but I don't know how.

The expected output should be something like "Hi Ole, you have allergies to gluten and eggs and should stay away from the foods garlic bread and chocolate cake"

Comment: "it should result in values linked to the name coming out, and elements from another dictionary." -  a well chosen example, with input and the corresponding expected output would be much clearer. About the Norwegian names, the code might be easier to understand when at least the variables have English names...

Comment: Have updated with expected output and English names

Comment: [Iterate through the dictionaries](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=08396876211A4E70A6B0AC728FCD044D) and compare the values.